# .NET Configuration Class save problem

Tags: c#, .net, app-config

When I change some config property and call Save() method to configuration object, and then change some config property and call Save() again I get exception because config was changed.

Text of exception: "The configuration file has been changed by another program."

So if user in run time changes something and do save and than changes something again and do save my app will throw exception. Am I right?

Shouldn't I be able to save config multiple times?

**EDIT:** Provided code sample.

```
ExeConfigurationFileMap map = new ExeConfigurationFileMap();
            map.LocalUserConfigFilename = UserConfig;
            map.RoamingUserConfigFilename = RoamingConfig;
            map.ExeConfigFilename = AppConfig;

            System.Configuration.Configuration combinedConfigFile = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(map, ConfigurationUserLevel.PerUserRoamingAndLocal);

            AddinConfiguration combinedConfig = (AddinConfiguration)combinedConfigFile.GetSection(sectionName);
            combinedConfig.Config = combinedConfigFile;
            return combinedConfig;
```

I have injected property Config into my section so I can use it to save configuration like this.

```
mySection.Config.Save();
```

Comment: Really strange error. I already made some app settings editor and I never runned into this error. Did you wrote the configuration sections you are trying to save or is it sections from the framework or is it sections designed through a code generator? Also are you opening the file as a current application configuration or as a mapped application configuration? A code sample could help too.

Comment: @Ucodia, I'm opening file as a mapped application configuration. I have written my own configuration section classes. I'll provide code sample in question above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The documentation states: "If the configuration file has changed since this Configuration object was created, a run-time error occurs." So after `Save()`, you need to destroy the configuration object and recreate it for multiple save operations to work normally.

Comment: Yes, I read that too, but it seems strange to me. So I cannot have singleton config object in my application?

Comment: No not at all. It is also ill advised to use singleton instances with config since it makes unit testing quite difficult.